# R - htmlParse() from XML package can't understand Russian letters

Tags: r, html-parsing

I'm looking at this bug for a couple of days, and looks like htmlParse function have an encoding problem, when parsing Russian symbols.

For example:

```
htmlParse("http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russia", encoding="UTF-8")
```

This page is in UTF-8 encoding, but to be sure, i'm focing htmlParse to encode it in UTF-8.

But in htmlParse() output, English symbols are right encoded, but Russian looks as typical wrong encoded symbols.

I'm using Windows 8 and my locale is Russian_Russia.1251. I think non Unicode locale is the problem here, because when i'm using this command in Ubuntu, everything working as expected, but Ubuntu has en_EN.UTF-8 locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you have tried, but this works fine for me:

```
doc <- htmlParse("http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russia", encoding="UTF-8")
 xpathSApply(doc,'//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/ul/li/a',xmlValue)
[1] "Russia (фильм)"    "Киры Муратовой"    "Наша Russia"      
    "Руша (Огайо)"      "англ."             "Россия (значения)"
```

Comment: I tested, and yes, the XPath output is valid, but when you print doc variable, you are getting wrong encoded symbols. Is it ok?